# R: For loop, need to use i and i+1 in same line, giving error non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm writing a script to split a csv file into a user defined number of files. I'm using For loops for the first time and ran into a problem I can't figure out how to solve. All but one line of the For loop works. When I replace that line with a temporary print command, the rest of the loop works fine.

When I try to run the script, I get the error code "non-numeric argument to binary operator". I know what's causing the error, but nothing I change in the For loop seems to fix the issue.

Here's an example of the For loop I wrote:

```
y <- as.numeric(readline("Enter number of files: "))
div <- nrow(df)/y
z <- c(0, seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 2))
x <- z[y]
k <- 2
for(i in 1:x){
if(i %% 2 == 0){
assign(paste0("div", i), div * k)
k <- k + 1
} else {
assign(paste0("div", i), paste0("div", i - 1) + 1)
}}
```

It's supposed to be a simplified way of assigning the `div` values, instead of writing all `div` values for each `y` like so:

```
y = 4
div1 = div + 1
div2 = div * 2
div3 = div2 + 1
div4 = div * 3
div5 = div4 + 1
```

The `div` values (specific row numbers) will be used in another For loop (same error occurs) to split the original `df` into `y` number of chunks. (`chunk2 = sample(df[div1:div2,])`)

I know the error is coming from the line `assign(paste0("div", i), paste0("div", i - 1) + 1)` and is caused by the `i - 1` and/or the `+ 1` at the end.

Things I have tried:

1. incrementing `i` within the loop

```
i = i - 1
i_two <- paste0("div", i)
i = i + 1
assign(paste0("div", i), i_two + 1)
```

2. asssigning a variable to `i - 1`

```
m = i - 1
assign(paste0("div", i), paste0("div", m) + 1)
```

3. converting `i` between integer, numeric, and double in various combinations & orders

```
assign(paste0("div", i), paste0("div", as.integer(as.double(i) - 1)) + 1)
```

4. combinations of converting `i` type and incrementing or assigning variable

I have read as many similar posts on this site as I could find (and that I could understand with my limited R knowledge & experience). I have noticed that a common cause for the error is that some defined variable is in the wrong type, when it should be numeric. I tried converting as many variables to numeric as I could, but that didn't seem to fix it either.

Nothing I've tried has worked, but I very well may have missed something. Any help is appreciated.

(Note: I'm trying to keep the script in base R & RTools. But, if necessary, I can use the tidyverse package. Also, I'm using my own environment in the script, so rest assured the variables aren't being saved to the global environment.)

EDIT: Resolved. Changed variable `div` to a list. The example of my code now looks like:

```
y <- as.numeric(readline("Enter number of files: "))
div <- list(list(),list())
div[[1]] <- nrow(df)/y
z <- c(0, seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 2))
x <- z[y]
k <- 2
for(i in 1:x){
if(i %% 2 == 0){
div[[2]][[i]] <- div[[1]] * k
k <- k +1
} else {
div[[2]][[i]] <- div[[i-1]] + 1
}}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Using `assign` along with it's partner `get()` is usually not a great idea is would be discouraged for new users. You would use `get()` to get the value of a variable from it's string name. So rather than `paste0("div", i-1) + 1` you probably meant `get(paste0("div", i-1)) + 1` because the `paste0` will just return a string.

Comment: As MrFlick noted, you are trying to add numbers to strings. `paste0("div", m) + 1` fails because `paste0("div", m)` returns a string, and then you want to add 1 to a string.

Comment: Are you after something like `number_of_files <- 7; split(mtcars, cut(1:nrow(mtcars), breaks = number_of_files, labels = FALSE))` , `mtcars` being example dataset?

Comment: Using `get(paste0("div", i-1)) + 1` worked. I knew it was something to do with a wrong type, but I assumed it was the `i` that was the wrong type and not the `paste0("div"...)` being a string. Thanks @MrFlick & @guasi

Comment: It may have worked, but again, using `get()` is strongly discouraged. There are almost always better ways to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Can you use a vector instead? `div[1] = nrow(df)/y + 1`, `div[2] = 2*nrow(df)/y`, `div[3] = div[2] + 1`, etc

Comment: @CPB After testing the script and running into a different issue (somewhat related to this question), I was going to rewrite the variables using a vector/list, like you suggested. Using a vector/list instead of the `paste0("div", i)` will hopefully solve both errors in my script and remove the need to use `get()` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: Changed variable `div` to a list. The example of my code now looks like:

```
y <- as.numeric(readline("Enter number of files: "))
div <- list(list(),list())
div[[1]] <- nrow(df)/y
z <- c(0, seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 2))
x <- z[y]
k <- 2
for(i in 1:x){
if(i %% 2 == 0){
div[[2]][[i]] <- div[[1]] * k
k <- k +1
} else {
div[[2]][[i]] <- div[[i-1]] + 1
}}
```